# Where to put virtual environments?

Tags: filesystem, virtualenv

There will be many virtual environments on my computer and I'd like to have a place where they are all stored. Somehow `$HOME` and subdirs don't seem to be good; too exposed. Any suggestions, or justifications why I'm thinking wrong?

I'm thinking about `/var/venv/`. Any thoughts?

Comment: What about permissions issues in that folder...?

Comment: How is `/var/venv` less exposed than `$HOME`?

Comment: @George I'll grant only that dir with writing permission. Bad idea?

Comment: @grooveplex Bad term, but by exposed I meant it's on or in short path from $HOME. Just don't want to have everything in my home dir.

Comment: you could hide it with a `.` before the folder name and still have it in `$HOME` dir...

Comment: @George Yes, and I can see that, e.g., python's virtual env has `.virtualenvs`. This is an option, but let's pretend I insist on not placing it in `$HOME`. Any opinions why this is bad or suggestions where I can place it?

Answer (score 1):

For venvs you will probably want them in a sub-directory of $HOME to avoid issues with security restrictions in apparmor or containers like docker.

Note the restrictions in this file:

```
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/python
```

In theory you could put them in /opt but venvs are really user specific and are expected in the users home directory.  Local isn't an option due to other distribution restrictions and the fact that /usr is offically assume to be shared on a network by the LSB.

I personally follow a modified version of the golang structure.

```
~build/
       +$language/
                +bin/
                |    venv/
                |      |---Python2.7
                |      +---Python3.6
                +pkg
                +src/
                    |
                    +--- my_work/..
                    |          |---repo1
                    |          +---other_project
                    |
                    +-- external-repo.com/..
```

This makes it easy to find and move content and it is compatible with the restrictions placed by security models, cgroups other restrictions that will become more critical as containers gain popularity.

Remember that venvs were original intended to be contained within the projects directory.  While realities on the core OS dependencies and major version changes have increased their use it is still preferable to keep them as close to the individual package, process, or user as possible.

Comment: Ok, I hear you and I'm learning. Would you mind elaborating on the security, cgroups and other restrictions, or at least provide some links? The more I think about use cases the more I'm in favour of moving it close to projects. However, I'm still not convinced why it's a bad idea to have a separate dir somewhere low.